# Neo4j ShortestPath to any node with a given property

Tags: neo4j, cypher, shortest-path

I am trying to work with ShortestPath in Neo4j. 
I want to find, for each node, its shortest path to any node with a given property.

In other words, for any node n1 I want the smallest length of the shortest paths to any node n2, n2 having a specific property. 
I currently use the following query but I believe it is inefficient as it would have to compute all shortest path between n1 and n2. A smarter way would be to stop looking as soon as we find a path such that `length(path)==1`.

```
MATCH path = shortestpath((n1:Node {has_ppt: False})-[:KNOWS]-(n2:Node {has_ppt: True}))
RETURN n1,n2,length(path)
LIMIT 5
```

Does anyone know how to do it differently ? Thanks

Comment: How many `n2` nodes (with that particular property) are in your graph?

Comment: n1 ~1M and n2~10k.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your `-[:KNOWS]-` pattern does not specify a variable length path (like `-[:KNOWS*..5]-`), so your `shortestpath` query is currently only trying to find paths of length 1. This is probably not what you intended.
2. You may want to try an iterative approach to finding a single instance of the shortest path. That is, repeatedly perform the following query (while incrementing the number in the `[:KNOWS*1]` pattern, to increment the desired path length) until you get a result:

   ```
   MATCH path = (n1:Node {has_ppt: False})-[:KNOWS*1]-(n2:Node {has_ppt: True})
   RETURN n1,n2,length(path)
   LIMIT 1;
   ```

Comment: Sorry I forgot it but I usually set a limit to 10. Good idea but that would require to parametrise the query and write a succession of queries depending upon each others. Thanks

Comment: Actually, since Cypher does not allow you to parametrize the variable length bounds (e.g., the `1` in `[:KNOWS*1]`), you actually have to generate a new query with every iteration.  But option 2 may still be the simplest way to get the answer.